# How to Highlight code of Libreoffice Math

Tags: libreoffice

When I am using libreoffice writer, I write long formulas and it would be easier if I could highlight the brackets as in any code editor.

Comment: Would it work to copy and paste the formula command into a code editor?  Then switch between the two windows with a keyboard shortcut such as `Alt+Tab`.

Comment: It's a solution, but not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be possible to do this by writing your own macro. To do this, write an [event listener](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/ProUNO/Basic/Listeners) for a particular keystroke, for example <kbd>%</kbd> like in Vi.

According to [xray](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=54217), the controller of the LO Math component supports [XUserInputInterception](http://www.openoffice.org/ui/accessibility/apiref/drafts/com/sun/star/awt/XUserInputInterception.html), which looks like it allows interception of keystrokes.

Although it looks possible, it looks like a difficult project, as I do not see any examples on the web to follow.

Comment: I was thinking if there was something already done